# Linking to an image in production using paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a RoR app that is using paperclip for upload images, and the color-box gem to view a larger version of the image. The problem is that it woks fine in development, but when I try to take the app to production it is looking for the image in the wrong place.

It tries to find the image in the root directory and gives an error that the file does not exist at URL/system/pictures/2/large/img.png, when it should be looking for the image in URL/s12/gallery/bsd/system/pictures/2/large/img.png

I don't know how to tell the app to look for the file in URL/s12/gallery/bsd/  Any help would be appreciated, let me know if more info is needed.

Here is how I am linking to the file in the view:

```
<%= link_to(image_tag(@project.picture.url(:thumb)), @project.picture.url(:large), :data=> { :colorbox => true }) %>
```

That gets the thumbnail to show up fine, but when clicked it says there is no file in the root directory...because there isn't.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
has_attached_file :photo, :styles => { :small => "150x150>" },
                  :url  => "/assets/products/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
                  :path => ":rails_root/public/assets/products/:id/:style/:basename.:extension"
```

you can set the url to change the defaults. also path is the system path where url is the url for the public